# Codelite and UnitTest++

Tags: c++, unittest++, codelite

Can anybody explain to me how the UnitTest++ integration in Codelite is supposed to work, i.e. where I am supposed to put UnitTest++'s header files and libUnitTest++.a?

I am working on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Seeing this question made me realise that I have never documented this plugin OO
So, please have a look at this page which I have just created [UnitTest++ In codelite IDE](http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/UnitTestPP) Eran

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Comment: The link is not working anymore :(